# bcp right truncation error but table format previously created using bcp unless I use -c

Tags: sql-server

Using the Tasks\Import Data option of SSMS I imported a CSV file. It was fine to leave everything as the default varchar(50).

I then ran this command to create a fmt file:

```
bcp [mydb].abp.blpu format nul -T -n -S server -f blpu.fmt
```

This produced this fmt file:

```
11.0
22
1       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   1     RECORD_IDENTIFIER                            Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   2     CHANGE_TYPE                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   3     PRO_ORDER                                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   4     UPRN                                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   5     LOGICAL_STATUS                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   6     BLPU_STATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   7     BLPU_STATE_DATE                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   8     PARENT_UPRN                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   9     X_COORDINATE                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   10    Y_COORDINATE                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   11    LATITUDE                                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   12    LONGITUDE                                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   13    RPC                                          Latin1_General_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   14    LOCAL_CUSTODIAN_CODE                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   15    COUNTRY                                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   16    START_DATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   17    END_DATE                                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   18    LAST_UPDATE_DATE                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   19    ENTRY_DATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   20    ADDRESSBASE_POSTAL                           Latin1_General_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   21    POSTCODE_LOCATOR                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR             2       50      ""   22    MULTI_OCC_COUNT                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I then emptied the table and ran this to import the same CSV file:

```
bcp [mydb].abp.blpu in "records.csv" -S server-T -F 2 -f "blpu.fmt" -t ","
```

But all I get is this multiple times.

> SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
> Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation

If I add -c then it works, but tells me it is overriding -f...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` switch in your first bcp command is telling it to generate a format file for "native type" data (i.e.: raw/binary SQL Server data):

```
bcp [mydb].abp.blpu format nul -T -n -S server -f blpu.fmt
```

If you're wanting to import text-based CSV data you'll need to generate a format file for "character type" data instead:

```
bcp [mydb].abp.blpu format nul -T -S server -f blpu.fmt -c -t, -r\n
```

This should generate a format file similar to the following (note the different data in the fifth column):

```
11.0
22
1       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   1     RECORD_IDENTIFIER                            Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   2     CHANGE_TYPE                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   3     PRO_ORDER                                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   4     UPRN                                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   5     LOGICAL_STATUS                               Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   6     BLPU_STATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   7     BLPU_STATE_DATE                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   8     PARENT_UPRN                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   9     X_COORDINATE                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   10    Y_COORDINATE                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   11    LATITUDE                                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   12    LONGITUDE                                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   13    RPC                                          Latin1_General_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   14    LOCAL_CUSTODIAN_CODE                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   15    COUNTRY                                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   16    START_DATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   17    END_DATE                                     Latin1_General_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   18    LAST_UPDATE_DATE                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   19    ENTRY_DATE                                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   20    ADDRESSBASE_POSTAL                           Latin1_General_CI_AS
21      SQLCHAR             2       50      ","   21    POSTCODE_LOCATOR                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
22      SQLCHAR             2       50      "\r\n"   22    MULTI_OCC_COUNT                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: That works, much appreciated. The only problem and searching I think there's no way round it, is all empty entries become null whereas using SSMS file import empty entries are empty strings which is what I want. So I guess I'll have to do a load of sql to mass update every column, which kind of defeats my purpose...